# Inline AJAX script passing variables to PHP

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I'm creating Referral URL detection plugin. I need that WP plugin enqueue AJAX script inline, which calls/pass variables to PHP script. When I trying to add same code to theme everything works (because it loads WP headers), but in plugin unfortunately not, I think that the AJAX need to be defined different.

Getting errors about `ABSPATH`

JS Script

```
function checkDocument() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/plugins/source-tracker/source-tracker.php",
            data: {
                server: '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>',
                source: document.referrer,
            },
            success: function (source) {
                console.dir(source)
            }
        });
    }

    jQuery(function (){
        checkDocument();
    });
```

It need to be calling for `class` with `__construct` function, which gets these 2 values and check them both

```
<?php

class SourceDetection {
    function check_referral($url){
        // CODE FOR CHECK UP BOTH URLS
    }

    function __construct(){
        $get_source_data = $_POST;
        $source = $this->check_referral($get_source_data);

        // METHOD FOR PROCESSING
        error_log($source);
    }
}
```

Maybe also the code style not the best for this, but I want to understand how the AJAX works in plugins.

Comment: 1. Can't you log the referrer directly from PHP? 2. You should use the REST API instead of calling custom PHP files

Comment: @kero 
1. PHP sometimes doesn't get the referrer, when JS get it right. that's why I want to check them both; 
2. maybe you have some examples?

Comment: The [documentation has good chapters on the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Comment: you shouldn't be making direct requests to PHP files inside your plugin or theme, that's not how you make AJAX requests to a WP install, and it's a major security vulnerability. Look up REST API endpoints as Kero recommends

Comment: also note that there isn't always a referrer, either because the user visited directly, proxies strip it out, or because the browser hides it for privacy

Comment: @TomJNowell maybe you have some examples how to do it with REST? 
I know about empty referrers, it's ok in my case of plugin usage :)

Comment: Kero linked you to the official docs which has one of the best examples already, unfortunately it's not copy pasta. You need to read the entire document.